# Chest supported row with big dumbbells

Tags: bodybuilding, dumbbells, resistancetraining, muscle-growth

I'am accustomed to performing chest supported row in a 30 degrees bench with dumbbells.

[image]

My current problem is that I'm performing it with 32kg dumbbell per side and they start to limit my range of motion at the top because they hurt the bench as they are quite bulky.

How can I solve that problem? The only idea I have is to do it in a bent over position with just the forehead or chest lying on the bench. But I doubt it will be comfortable with future heavy weight. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only thing I could suggest is to alter hand position slightly like this so the dumbells are more parallel.
[image]
The forearm rotation will change to biceps activation slightly but provided you keep the elbow at the same roughly 45° angle, the back involvement should be pretty much the same.